# Connection Interrupted. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

Tags: php, mysql, firefox

I am calling a PHP-Script belonging to a MySQL/PHP web application using FF3. I run XAMPP on localhost. All I get is this:

> Connection Interrupted
>   The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>   The network link was interrupted while negotiating a connection. Please try again.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880454/http-localhost8080-not-redirecting-to-opensso-login-page

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of possible solutions ... depends on the "why" ... so it ends up being a bit of trial and error. On a fresh install, that's tricky to determine. But, if you made a recent "major" change that's a place to start looking - like modifying virtual hosts or adding/enabling XDebug.

Here's a list of things I've used/done/tried in the past

- check for infinite loops ... in particular looping through a SQL fetch result which works 99% of the time except the 1% it doesn't. In one case, I was using the results of two previous queries as the upper and lower bounds of a for loop ... and occasionally got a upper bound of a UINT max ... har har har (*vomit*)
- copying the ./php/libmysql.dll to the windows/system32 directory (Particularly if you see `Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting` in your log files ... check out: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1050)
- if you modify PHP's error_reporting at runtime ... in certain circumstances this can cause PHP to degenerate into an unstable state if, say, in your PHP code you modify the superglobals or fiddle around with other deep and personal background system variables (Nah, who would ever do such evil hackery? *ahem*)
- if you convert your MySQL to something other than MyISAM or mysqli

> There is a known bug with MySQL related to MyISAM, the UTF8 character set and indexes (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4541)
>   Solution is to use InnoDB dialect (eg sql `set GLOBAL storage_engine='InnoDb';`)

- Doing that changes how new tables are created ... which might *slightly* alter the way results are returned to a fetch statement ... leading to an infinite loop, a malformed dataset, etc. (although this change should not hang the database itself)

Other helpful items are to ramp up the debug reporting for PHP and apache in their config files and restart the servers. The log files sometimes give a clue as to at least *where* the problem might reside. If it happens after your page content was finished it's more likely in the php settings. If it's during page construction, check your PHP code. Etc. etc.

Hope the above laundry list helps somebody someday ... probably myself when I run into it again and come back here looking for "how the heck did I fix it last time?" ... :)

Answer (score 5):

It's possible that your script could be caught in an infinite loop. If that doesn't apply, then I'd check the error logs like TimB suggested.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the PHP script you're calling is failing without returning a valid response. Depending on the level of logging that you have set up, this should generate an error in the Apache logfile, which will give you some idea of the problem. I'm not familiar with XAMPP, but you should be able to find out where the logs are, and look for an error that occurred at the time you made your request to the PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

copying libmysql.dll to apache\bin folder may help you overcome this strange error

Comment: Thanks tata9999.  I've been plagued with this problem for about a week now.  Your suggestion did the trick.

Comment: I used mysql_pconnect and the error disappeared.
However tata999 hits the bulls eye.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem **Upgrading the xampp\php\ext\xdebug\php_xdebug.dll**
(changed to php xdebug v.2.0.5-5.3-vc9 )

Comment: Thanks, Raul, this solved my issue (although I did end up needing a different version of the dll than you).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what i did.

I issued the http get command through php cli script, and as it turns out I had declared one class twice somewhere.

By the way , i use AMPPS on an mac

Hope this helps some one!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the request with Firebug enabled and see what info you can get out of that; I always find that using wget is helpful for seeing the raw HTTP interaction without worrying about Firefox's UI elements interfering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using certificates for ssl in Windows 2008 Server(iis 7) from old selfssl tool(iis 6), that is the problem. Sometimes Microsoft releases patches which can destruct all these old certificates. The solution is to generate them again.

Comment: It's not an IIS problem, since he said he's using XAMPP, where the A stands for Apache.

Answer (score 0):

copying `libmysql.dll` to `apache\bin` folder may help you overcome this strange error

Indeed this helped me to solve this problem

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Answer (score 0):

Incase the issue is not working this did the trick for me.
1. I got a new zip directory for PHP and connected it with apache
2. I searched for the libmysql in the new php and inserted this to the apache/bin
its this libmysql.dll that is needed there and not the one form mySQL/bin.

ok at least thats the one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a very similar issue - which doesn't apply to the person who asked this question - but may be of help to others who are reading this page...

I had an issue where in certain cases  PHP 5.4 + eAccelerator = connection reset.  There was no error output in any log files, and it only happened on certain URLs, which made it difficult to diagnose.   Turns out it only happened for certain PHP code / certain PHP files, and was due to some incompatibilities with specific PHP code and eAccelerator.  Easiest solution was to disable eAccelerator for that specific site, by adding the following to .htaccess file

php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0

php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0

(or equivalent lines in php.ini):

eaccelerator.enable="0"

eaccelerator.optimizer="0"