# http://localhost:8080 not redirecting to opensso login page

Tags: networking, websocket, liferay, tomcat6, opensso

I have my Tomcat server of Liferay running on port 8080. When I am trying to access the application from server by typing url `http://localhost:8080` , it is not redirecting to the Login page but giving me the error:

```
The Connection to abc.xyz.com was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

Here abc.xyz.com is the URL of my Opensso Login page. No errors are logged in stdout.log and catalina.log.  But when I am typing the URL the login page is coming. Tried this in different IE and Mozilla but facing the same issue.

Comment: The same thing was working some 3 days back, can anyone tell what may cause the issue? do i need any dll files or IPV6 configuration?

Comment: In firebug i can see it http://localhost:8080 is redirecting to my login page but the connection is interrupted

Comment: any mismatch between http and https protocol declarations and the actual protocol that your opensso login page is available on?

Comment: My issue got resolved by changing in hosts file