# The connection to the server was reset while thepage was loading php error

Tags: php, database, mysqli

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbConnection.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Book Club</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method ="post" action ="register.php">

        <?php
        //get the values from the form, using the POST method.
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $profession = $_POST['profession'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $date_of_birth = $_POST['date_of_birth'];
        $country_of_residence = $_POST['country_of_residence'];
        $email = $_POST['first_name'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT username FROM account WHERE username = '$username' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) ;  

        $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO user (first_name,last_name,profession,gender,date_of_birth,country_of_residence,email,username,password)" .
        "VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$profession', '$gender', '$date_of_birth', '$country_of_residence', '$email', '$username', '$password')";
        //echo $queryInsert;
        //echo $queryInsert;
        $resultInsert = mysqli_query($link,$queryInsert); 
        header('Location: login.php');
        echo "<h3>The following user has been successfully added:  </h3>";
      ?>

    Click <a href="admin.php"> here </a> to go back to the home page.
</body>
</html>
```

Stuck with that error message since forever. Unable to find out where i went wrong with my connection or code. Anyone mind helping me? Really cant think of where my error is. Cant decipher whether is it a connection or code issue at all.

Comment: its not `include 'dbConnection.php';` . Change it to `include('dbConnection.php');`

Comment: Also, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124392/connection-interrupted-the-connection-to-the-server-was-reset-while-the-page-wa

Comment: hmm i changed accordingly but it still has the same error

Comment: What `<form method ="post" action ="register.php">` is doing there ? Share your full code along with `include 'dbConnection.php';`. Plz.

Comment: What error you are getting ? Please paste your error also.

Comment: @NanaPartykar <?php

$HOST = "localhost";
$USERNAME = "root";
$PASSWORD = "";
$DB = "bookclub";
$link = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, $DB);

if (!$link) {
    die(mysqli_error($link));
}

?>

Answer (score 1):

You have added this line in the code.
 header('Location: login.php');

This means the page will redirect to login.php. If you named the above page as login.php then there formed a redirect loop ( Again again redirecting to the same page ). So browser cannot render that page.